Where should I place mini-split heads in a converted building?
I've got a 600 sq. ft. metal building I'm turning into an ADU. The interior is insulated with 2" of closed cell spray foam all the way around, and finished with 1/2" drywall on 1x4 furring strips.
I want to put in a mini split system because there's no attic space, but I don't know what the right placement is for the heads. I was thinking a 21k btu system with a 9k in the closet and 12k in the living room, but I'm worried that air won't get into the bedroom and bathroom and we like it cold at night.
I was thinking maybe a transfer fan in the bedroom/bathroom walls to the closet... But at that point I'm wondering if I could just put a single 21k head in the living room and put transfer fans between the living room and bedroom/closet/bathroom/bedroom 2.
Anyone who knows a little more about airflow want to tell me the best way to tackle this? Thanks


One alternative is a mini-split with a ducted inside head for distribution.

I am thinking I might have to go this route, but I didn't want to exposed ductwork. Unfortunately I don't think it's an option at this point to just have two outlets. At least that seems to be the consensus.

A drop ceiling hides all ductwork sins above it.

Would I be able to use drywall to make it more decorative? Or would that cause condensation problems?

Is a "pancake" style of low-static ducted head an option?

9.25m x 6.22m total, bedroom 2m x2.34m in normal units.
If want to have cold in bedroom then need at last 3k in each bedroom and 9-12k in living room. And for sure good air vent to force air outside from bathroom to prevent mold.
Do not worry about closet, You not live there and for that couple minutes to take/put something there normal diffusion is enough.

I agree 100% with you, but cannot find 3000btu units anywhere in the US.  Where do you find them? The smallest I can find are 9000btu. and they are probably too big for the small bedrooms.  I have needs for lower BTU units, so your info would be appreciated.

Yeah I was thinking the same thing but I cannot find any 3,000 BTU units, just like the user above me said.

Looked for them and do not see. 5k, 7k, 9k but 3k now see only for caravans. That only here in Europe, nothing less than 9k in America.
